# How do I find the Windows common application data folder using Python?

Tags: python, windows, application-data, common-files

I would like my application to store some data for access by all users. Using Python, how can I find where the data should go?

Comment: What operating system is this for?

Comment: @tgray, it's in the question title.

Comment: That's a little embarassing...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you don't want to add a dependency for a third-party module like winpaths, I would recommend using the environment variables already available in Windows:

- [**What environment variables are available in Windows?**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-recognized-environment-variables)

Specifically you probably want `ALLUSERSPROFILE` to get the location of the common user profile folder, which is where the Application Data directory resides.

e.g.:

```
C:\> python -c "import os; print os.environ['ALLUSERSPROFILE']"
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users
```

**EDIT**: Looking at the winpaths module, it's using ctypes so if you wanted to just use the relevant part of the code without installing winpath, you can use this (obviously some error checking omitted for brevity).

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes, windll

CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA = 35

_SHGetFolderPath = windll.shell32.SHGetFolderPathW
_SHGetFolderPath.argtypes = [wintypes.HWND,
                            ctypes.c_int,
                            wintypes.HANDLE,
                            wintypes.DWORD, wintypes.LPCWSTR]


path_buf = wintypes.create_unicode_buffer(wintypes.MAX_PATH)
result = _SHGetFolderPath(0, CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, 0, 0, path_buf)
print path_buf.value
```

Example run:

```
C:\> python get_common_appdata.py
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data
```

Comment: What if the user is on a non-English version of Windows? Does ALLUSERSPROFILE still apply?

Comment: @Out Into Space - it does at least on the Italian version of  windows, not sure about other non-English versions.

Comment: What is the relevant place then ? Is it `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\MySoftware` provided by `_SHGetFolderPath` or `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\MySoftware` provided by `os.environ['ALLUSERSPROFILE']` ?  Is the `\Application Data\\` needed (first solution) or not (second solution) ?

Comment: Use `ctypes.create_unicode_buffer`, which works in both PY2 and PY3. It was only accidentally in `wintypes` in PY2 due to its use of `from ctypes import *`.

Comment: @Basj, programs should use `SHGetFolderPathW`. `"%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data"` should only be used in batch files. The preferred environment variables in Vista+ are `ProgramData` and `Public`.

Comment: @eryksun `"%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data"`  this would give : `C:\ProgramData\Application Data` on Vista/7/8 !

Comment: @Basj: It should exist as a hidden NTFS junction that points back at `C:\ProgramData` (or wherever), but I'd update a batch file to use the newer `%ProgramData%`.

Comment: Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/installation-context

Comment: ... and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid

Answer (score 15):

From http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=7354

```
homedir = os.path.expanduser('~')

# ...works on at least windows and linux. 
# In windows it points to the user's folder 
#  (the one directly under Documents and Settings, not My Documents)


# In windows, you can choose to care about local versus roaming profiles.
# You can fetch the current user's through PyWin32.
#
# For example, to ask for the roaming 'Application Data' directory:
#  (CSIDL_APPDATA asks for the roaming, CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA for the local one)
#  (See microsoft references for further CSIDL constants)
try:
    from win32com.shell import shellcon, shell            
    homedir = shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, shellcon.CSIDL_APPDATA, 0, 0)

except ImportError: # quick semi-nasty fallback for non-windows/win32com case
    homedir = os.path.expanduser("~")
```

To get the app-data directory for all users, rather than the current user, just use `shellcon.CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA` instead of `shellcon.CSIDL_APPDATA`.

Comment: OP asked for data accessible by all users

Comment: @Jason S: I've added a note re app-data for all users.

Comment: The constant value corresponds with Environment.SpecialFolder Enum documented in MS website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at http://ginstrom.com/code/winpaths.html. This is a simple module that will retrieve Windows folder information. The module implements `get_common_appdata` to get the  App Data folder for all users.

Comment: +1 This looks very useful, thanks, but Jays answer gets me what I want with no added dependency

Answer (score 3):

*Previous answer removed due to incompatibility with non-US versions of Windows, and Vista.*

**EDIT:**  To expand on Out Into Space's answer, you would use the 
`winpaths.get_common_appdata` function.  You can get winpaths using `easy_install winpaths` or by going to the pypi page, http://pypi.python.org/pypi/winpaths/, and downloading the .exe installer.

Comment: Unfortunately, that will not hold up on non-English OS's.

Comment: Could you be more specific, please?

Comment: I believe he means that "Documents and Settings" is localized in non-English copies of XP. Also, it is possible to change the location of this folder via the registry. Finally, Vista names this folder "Users" instead. Lesson: don't hard-code it.

Comment: But using the winpaths.get_common_appdata uses the registry value, correct?  This method should be cross-lingual.

Comment: I'd suggest removing the first part of the answer, hard coding this value would be wrong for vista or any non english XP

Answer (score 3):

You can access all of your OS environment variables using the `os.environ` dictionary in the `os` module.  Choosing which key to use from that dictionary could be tricky, though.  In particular, you should remain aware of internationalized (i.e., non-English) versions of Windows when using these paths.

`os.environ['ALLUSERSPROFILE']` should give you the root directory for all users on the computer, but after that be careful not to hard code subdirectory names like "Application Data," because these directories don't exist on non-English versions of Windows.  For that matter, you may want to do some research on what versions of Windows you can expect to have the ALLUSERSPROFILE environment variable set (I don't know myself -- it may be universal).

My XP machine here has a COMMONAPPDATA environment variable which points to the All Users\Application Data folder, but my Win2K3 system does not have this environment variable.

Answer (score 3):

Since [SHGetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181.aspx) is deprecated, you can also use [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx) in Vista and newer. This also lets you look up more paths than SHGetFolderPath will. Here's a stripped-down example (full code [available on Gist](https://gist.github.com/mkropat/7550097)):

```
import ctypes, sys
from ctypes import windll, wintypes
from uuid import UUID

class GUID(ctypes.Structure):   # [1]
    _fields_ = [
        ("Data1", wintypes.DWORD),
        ("Data2", wintypes.WORD),
        ("Data3", wintypes.WORD),
        ("Data4", wintypes.BYTE * 8)
    ] 

    def __init__(self, uuid_):
        ctypes.Structure.__init__(self)
        self.Data1, self.Data2, self.Data3, self.Data4[0], self.Data4[1], rest = uuid_.fields
        for i in range(2, 8):
            self.Data4[i] = rest>>(8 - i - 1)*8 & 0xff

class FOLDERID:     # [2]
    LocalAppData            = UUID('{F1B32785-6FBA-4FCF-9D55-7B8E7F157091}')
    LocalAppDataLow         = UUID('{A520A1A4-1780-4FF6-BD18-167343C5AF16}')
    RoamingAppData          = UUID('{3EB685DB-65F9-4CF6-A03A-E3EF65729F3D}')

class UserHandle:   # [3]
    current = wintypes.HANDLE(0)
    common  = wintypes.HANDLE(-1)

_CoTaskMemFree = windll.ole32.CoTaskMemFree     # [4]
_CoTaskMemFree.restype= None
_CoTaskMemFree.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]

_SHGetKnownFolderPath = windll.shell32.SHGetKnownFolderPath     # [5] [3]
_SHGetKnownFolderPath.argtypes = [
    ctypes.POINTER(GUID), wintypes.DWORD, wintypes.HANDLE, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_wchar_p)
] 

class PathNotFoundException(Exception): pass

def get_path(folderid, user_handle=UserHandle.common):
    fid = GUID(folderid) 
    pPath = ctypes.c_wchar_p()
    S_OK = 0
    if _SHGetKnownFolderPath(ctypes.byref(fid), 0, user_handle, ctypes.byref(pPath)) != S_OK:
        raise PathNotFoundException()
    path = pPath.value
    _CoTaskMemFree(pPath)
    return path

common_data_folder = get_path(FOLDERID.RoamingAppData)

# [1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931.aspx
# [2] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457.aspx
# [3] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx
# [4] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680722.aspx
# [5] http://www.themacaque.com/?p=954
```