# dynamically adding Python sys.path entries that refer to inside a .zip file

Tags: python, python-2.7, path

I have a Python program which adds something dynamically to `sys.path`. It works fine, but I'd like to distribute my Python program as a .zip file where `__main__.py` runs.

Can I add entries to `sys.path` from the zip file? After searching around a bit, I found the [`pkgutil` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html) but I can't figure out what will work.

**note:** the stuff I need to add in `sys.path` includes `.pyd` and `.dll` files for Windows.

Comment: you cant execute a zip file... I dont understand the question I think

Comment: I thought you don't know what you're talking about until I saw your reputation.

Comment: You *can* execute a zip file: http://bugs.python.org/issue1739468

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but I'll have a crack at answering it anyway ...

Unfortunately, while you can import from a zipfile by adding it to `sys.path`:

> [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) contains a list of strings providing search locations for
>   modules and packages. It is initialized from the PYTHONPATH
>   environment variable and various other installation- and
>   implementation-specific defaults. **Entries in [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) can name
>   directories on the file system, zip files,** and potentially other
>   “locations” (see the [`site`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#module-site) module) that should be searched for modules,
>   such as URLs, or database queries. Only strings and bytes should be
>   present on [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path); all other data types are ignored. The encoding of
>   bytes entries is determined by the individual [*path entry finders*](http://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-path-entry-finder).
>
> *source: http://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#path-entry-finders*

... that doesn't extend to `.pyd` and `.dll` files:

> Any files may be present in the ZIP archive, but only files `.py` and
>   `.py[co]` are available for import. **ZIP import of dynamic modules (`.pyd`,
>   `.so`) is disallowed.**
>
> *source: http://docs.python.org/3/library/zipimport.html*

I'm not aware of any way of working around this restriction.

Comment: is there a good workaround? e.g. if I unzip the .pyd and .dll files somewhere and add them to sys.path, where is a good place to do this? I don't want to modify the default Python installation, and if I run the .zip file 100 times I don't want it to generate 100 temporary directories.

Comment: @JasonS I've never developed specifically for Windows (nor am I a Windows user), but it looks like [winpaths](http://ginstrom.com/code/winpaths.html) might be helpful - presumably you'd want one of the "App Data" variants. Found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/626796/1014938), by the way.