# {Import from File} Error when importing from other directory

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, import

I want to import a file from `%appdata%/.EliteCS/sysfiles/gui.py` however whenever I do, this comes up.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Documents\Elite\elite_computer_system.py", line 10, in <
module>
    import gui
ImportError: No module named gui

C:\Users\Samuel\Documents\Elite>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

My `%appdata%/.EliteCS/sysfiles/` folder contains 2 files: `__init__.py` (empty py file) and gui.py, a py file full of definitions, but no actual code. When asking python to import it thus:

```
sys.path.insert(0, '%appdata%/.EliteCS/sysfiles')
import gui
```

it gives the error, same for `from gui import *` instead of the import gui line.
Would someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. I can't work out what's wrong.

Comment: @MartijnPieters whoops, that may be the error. I'll get back to you.

Comment: no, the typo was in the question. The DIR is named .EliteCS/sysfiles

Comment: `'%appdata%'` is not expanded by Python; that won't work as is.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I've now changed it to a finite path: Now it works like a dream. Thank you so much, +1 to you. Put it as an answer, and I'll accept+upvote it.

Comment: I've removed the 'how I solved it' part; best to leave the question just that, a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%appdata%` variable is not expanded by Python for you.

Either use an absolute path to the application data folder, or retrieve the `%appdata%` variable from the system and concatenate that with `.EliteCS/sysfiles`.

See [How do I find the Windows common application data folder using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626796/how-do-i-find-the-windows-common-application-data-folder-using-python) for methods to retrieve system paths like `appdata`.

If you use the environment option, that'd be:

```
import os
import sys

sys.insert(0, os.path.join(os.environ['APPDATA'], '.EliteCS', 'sysfiles'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not place gui.py in the same folder as the file you are running?
Then you can just say `import gui` and it will definitly run.

Comment: The whole point is that the files live in a mini FS in %appdata%/.EliteCS and the .py can be moved wherever you want it.