# AttributeError: module 'ctypes.wintypes' has no attribute 'create_unicode_buffer'

Tags: python, compiler-errors, ctypes, python-3.5

This is a part of my code:

```
import os

def _get_appdata_path():
    import ctypes
    from ctypes import wintypes, windll
    CSIDL_APPDATA = 26
    _SHGetFolderPath = windll.shell32.SHGetFolderPathW
    _SHGetFolderPath.argtypes = [wintypes.HWND,
                                 ctypes.c_int,
                                 wintypes.HANDLE,
                                 wintypes.DWORD,
                                 wintypes.LPCWSTR]
    path_buf = wintypes.create_unicode_buffer(wintypes.MAX_PATH)
    result = _SHGetFolderPath(0, CSIDL_APPDATA, 0, 0, path_buf)
    return path_buf.value
```

But when I call `wintypes.create_unicode_buffer()` I get the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'ctypes.wintypes' has no attribute 'create_unicode_buffer'
```

I am using Python 3.5.1. What could I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626796/how-do-i-find-the-windows-common-application-data-folder-using-python#comment33587651_626927

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use ctypes.create_unicode_buffer, which works in both PY2 and PY3. It was only accidentally in wintypes in PY2 due to its use of `from ctypes import *`. :D